# How to save specific variable in for loop in to the database?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a code script that get group id and run some wmi commands for this groups.
I have several wmi commands like get ip, get computer manufacturer, get computer username and so on. I want to save this outputs in database. Like after get ip, get database and write it on ip column. And the same things for other parameters like manufacturer and username.

How can i do it? Im so confused because in my for loop I run all the commands in order.

```
   query = f"select wmic_id from group_wmic where group_id = '{group_id}'"
    cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
    cursor.execute(query)
    wmic_ids = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in wmic_ids:
        wmic_id = row["wmic_id"]
        query = f"select command_line from wmic_commands where id = '{wmic_id}'"
        cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
        cursor.execute(query)
        command_line = cursor.fetchall()
        for data in command_line:
          cmd_line = data['command_line']
          output = wmi.query(cmd_line)
          result = json.dumps(output)
          mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO wmi_inventory (wmi_data, date) 
                                    VALUES (%s, %s) """
          now = datetime.now()
          dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")
          record = (result, dt_string)
          cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query, record)
          connection.commit()
```

Comment: Avoid using f-strings for SQL queries like this; instead, use a placeholder in the query then pass the value to `.execute()` separately, like you do with the INSERT.

Comment: For your question, I'm not sure what you want exactly; would you be able to write it out in more detail, perhaps with a couple of examples? That will help us help you, or it may even help you directly?

Comment: I edited it, i guess i gave more details

Comment: It's still not very clear what you want to do; you're going to need more details in order to be able to implement it

Answer (score 0):

For being more clear,

I have commands like:

```
SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem
```

which gives me the username of computer. or `SELECT Manufacturer, Model FROM Win32_ComputerSystem` it gives me the manufacturer.

In this part of my code

```
query = f"select command_line from wmic_commands where id = '{wmic_id}'"
    cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
    cursor.execute(query)
    command_line = cursor.fetchall()
    **for data in command_line:
      cmd_line = data['command_line']
      output = wmic.query(cmd_line)**
      result = json.dumps(output)
      mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO wmi_inventory (wmi_data, date) 
                                VALUES (%s, %s) """
      now = datetime.now()
      dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")
      record = (result, dt_string)
      cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query, record)
      connection.commit()
```

I execute all these queries in my for loop. And save the output as a json data in my database. But i want to save outputs in to the database like when i execute the username commands, save it in to username column.